# Checking luggage Dublin-LHR-Doha-Kilimanjaro

Tags: luggage, lhr, dub, doh, jro

I am flying BA from Dublin to LHR then Qatar Airlines from LHR to Doha and Kilimanjaro.  Will I be able to check my luggage through from Dublin to Kilimanjaro?

Comment: Is your ticket from a single booking ? Have you inquired with BA ?

Comment: Not just Virtual - all the important details are covered there.